# What does it mean when a party has a mandate?

Tags: democracy, australia

In the media I hear politicians say things such as "we have a mandate" and "the opposition has a mandate". What exactly does it mean when a particular party of government has a mandate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a democracy a politician can claim a 'mandate' if their policy has been concretely backed by the electorate - for example, if the policy is in the manifesto that the party stood on, successfully, for election. Another example could be a policy backed by referendum.

From the [OED](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mandate):

> the authority to carry out a policy, regarded as given by the electorate to a party or candidate that wins an election:
>   he called an election to seek a mandate for his policies

Comment: Just to be clear - "have a mandate" is a pretty wishy-washy term, used by anyone who feels like it (from a guy who won 80% of the vote, to one who won just under 53%).

Comment: "You have no mandate" is a criticism that likewise doesn't seem to carry that much real weight, at least here in the UK.

Comment: In practice, if a party has to say it has a mandate - then it usually doesn't.